# Where is my master.key and how can i regenerate it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused on the whole masterkey situation.

I did:
`EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit`

which, from what I have read, is supposed to generate a master key file, but it isn't.

I ended up running: `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY="$(< config/master.key)"` and it sent through a master key code, but where is this? I normally would think to just ignore this since it "worked" but I copied this app from another app i have to clone it and it's using the same master key as the other.  I want them to be different so I am trying to understand what's going on here.

I deleted the credentials.yml file and redid the `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit` but the code stayed the same.

Questions:

Where exactly is the master.key file? (I assumed it would be under config/master.key but isn't)
How can I "regenerate" the key?
(found https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rails-52-credentials-tricks.html which solved regeneration, but still where exactly is the file?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials.

If you set the key as an environment variable then the key is there, on the variable, it's not saved into a file and that's why you can't find it.

Check here to know about heroku's environment variables https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-cli

Run `rails secret` to create a new key.